# Fastlane uses default iOS Simulator despite device: "desired device" in run_tests lane

Tags: xctest, simulator, fastlane

In my FastFile, I have defined:

```
  run_tests(
    scheme: "TestsScheme",
    device: "iPad mini (6th generation)",
    output_directory: "./report_unit_tests",
    skip_slack: true,
  )
```

I did verify that a simulator with this name actually exists in xcode.

Despite this, the unit tests 'always' run on the iPhone SE (3rd generation). This device is the last one in the list in the xcode devices & simulators screen.

I also tried with:

```
  run_tests(
    scheme: "TestsScheme",
    devices: ["iPad mini (6th generation)"],
    output_directory: "./report_unit_tests",
    skip_slack: true,
  )
```

I got this working by deleting all simulators from xcode, leaving only the one(s) that I want the tests to run on.

What is going wrong?
Have I misconfigured something?
Is Fastlane missing my config here?

I am using:
fastlane (2.210.1)
Bundler 2.3.24
ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468)
gem 3.2.3